# Why can't I use the classname instead of self in objective c

Tags: objective-c, oop, class-method

It's just something which is not logical for me. Sure it's useful to call methods within in a class by the self-keyword. But why isn't it possible calling it by the own classname??

e.g. 
`[MyClassWhereIAmActuallyIn anyRandomMethod];` instead of  `[self anyRandomMethod];`

Comment: Instance Method vs Class Method difference.

Answer (score 2):

Because that has a different meaning.

```
[self someMethod]
```

sends `someMethod` to the object, whose reference is stored in the (slightly magic) variable `self`.

```
[SomeClass someMethod]
```

sends `someMethod` to the class object (yes, classes are objects, too), which contains the meta-information for class `SomeClass`.

Two different objects ("receivers"). Also note, that there are class methods in Objective-C (i.e., you can take advantage of the fact, that classes are objects, and define new methods for them). Observe:

```
@interface SomeClass
    - (void) someMethod;
    + (void) someMethod;
@end
```

These are completely different methods, intended for completely different receivers. The method tagged with `-` is an instance method (will be used, e.g., with `self`). The method tagged with `+` is a class method (and will be used with the class object).

Comment: ok, that makes sense. But when I'm calling my own class methods... wouldn't it be logical to be able to call it by the class name as well??

Comment: Not sure, whether I understand the question... What do you mean by "class method" here? There is nothing special about class methods (the `+` guys). A method call is always `[<receiver> message...]` in Objective-C. And a class is a perfectly fine receiver. But I suspect, that we might mean different things by "class method".

Comment: CLASS-A h-file i declared a method:
`+(void)greet;`

CLASS-A m-file 
`+(void)greet {NSLog(@"hi")};`

CLASS-B m-file call method:
`[CLASS-A greet];`

CLASS-A m-file call method:
`[CLASS-A greet];` // why not `[self greet];` ??

I thought that I can just call the own Class-Method by calling it with `[self greet]` but now I guess I can't use it because "self" represents just my Class-Objects and not the Class iself??

Comment: I still cannot really understand your question... Your "Class-Objects" are your "Class[es]". Do you mean "instances"? You cannot call a class method (`+`) in an instance method (`-`, even if it's an instance method of the same class) using `self` as the receiver, since `self` in the instance method refers to the instance. The class is a totally different object.

Answer (score 1):

You can call class method ('+') like that. Self is a pointer to an instance of your class in instance methods ('-'), self points to the singleton Class-object when you are in class methods ('+').

Answer (score 0):

In OOP this is the difference between the class object and an instance of that class object. When you create a method, you specify whether it is a class method (`+`) or an instance method (`-`). Once the method is defined you need to call it in the appropriate way (on the class object or on an instance of that class).